# Python: Argument Parse to Obtain Desired Information

Tags: python, dictionary

new to Python here. So I'm trying to figure out how to work with argument parse, to be more command line friendly for people to use. I have a text file (student.txt):

```
Name : Brandon
Age  : 16
Gender : Male
Name : Alex
Age  : 18
Gender : Male
Name : Calvin
Age  : 17
Gender : Male
Name : Sarah
Age  : 19
Gender : Female
Name : Ellie
Age  : 15
Gender : Female
Name : Sam
Age  : 19
Gender : Female
```

Code I've done (Not sure how to go about after this):

```
import argparse


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Script to parse')
parser.add_argument('--filter',
                    help='Filter')
parser.add_argument('--file',
                    help='Name of the file')
args = parser.parse_args()

with open ('args.file','r') as readfile:
    flag=False
    student={}
    temp={}
    student_lst = 'Name,Age,Gender'.split(',')

    for line in readfile.readlines():
        if flag:
            key,value = line.split (':')
            temp[key.strip()]=value.strip()
    
            if 'Gender' in line:
                student[temp['Name']] = temp
                temp = {}

        if 'Name' in line:
            temp['Name']=line.split(':')[1].strip()
            if args.filter in student_lst or not args.filter:
                flag = True
            else:
                flag = False
```

Expected output, the filters are specific:

```
exercise.py --file student.txt --filter_Gender Female --filter_Age 19
```

Would give me  :

```
{'Sarah': {'Age': '19', 'Gender': 'Female', 'Name': 'Sarah'},
 'Sam': {'Age': '19', 'Gender': 'Female', 'Name': 'Sam'}}
```

IF cmd line is:

```
exercise.py --file student.txt
```

Would give me all the dictionary data of the students.

Basically, based on the user input on the cmd line using argparse. It would filter out, and give me the full information of that particular data. Would appreciate any help at all, would prefer if the overall code does not differ much.
Many thanks!! :)

Comment: What's constant about your problem and what's variable? Are you looking for a script that works regardless of the fields included in the file? (i.e. someone could add 'Eyes' and it would still work and you could filter by it?) Would values in the input always be separated by a colon and the values not contain any colons? What about age: only filtering for specific ages, or ages over/under some value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are naming your command line arguments is not really workable, as the names of the actual parameters change depending on your filter.

One way to do it is to have two arguments per filter. So keep the parameter name as `--filter` and pass a filter name and value. Your command line could instead be written as

```
exercise.py --file student.txt --filter Gender Female --filter Age 19
```

To achieve this you can instead create your argparse argument like

```
parser.add_argument('--filter', help='Filter', nargs=2, action='append')
```

Here `nargs` means that this parameter takes two arguments and `action='append'` means the values are stored in a list instead of a dict (where previous values are overwritten by newer ones).

Now the code could look like

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Script to parse')
parser.add_argument('--filter', help='Filter', nargs=2, action='append')
parser.add_argument('--file', help='Name of the file')
args = parser.parse_args()
# print(args)

with open(args.file, 'r') as f:
    students = []

    for line in f:
        key, value = map(str.strip, line.split(':'))
        if key == 'Name':
            students.append({})
        students[-1][key] = value

    def filtfn(stu):
        for key, val in args.filter:
            if stu[key] != val:
                return False
        return True

    print('*******')
    for result in filter(filtfn, students):
        print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as you haven't gotten more into development/you don't **have** to use argparse, I would strongly suggest looking into the library Click. It does the same job as argparse, it's just way easier and more intuitive to work with.

Second, I would suggest storing the student items in a `.json` file. This makes it very easy to read and write to, as a JSON file has the same structure as a Python dictionary. So your structure could look like:

```
student_dict = {'students':
 [{'name': 'Brandon', 'age': 16}]
}
```

To get all students:

```
for student in student_dict['students']:
  print(student)
```

It would also be really simple to filter out students by name, like:

```
for student in student_dict['students']:
  if student['name'] == 'Jessica':
    print('This is Jessica')
```

---

I don't have much experience with argparse, but if you swap to Click I'd be happy to help!